# Semantic UI React not displaying

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I am decently new to react and am now trying to add semantic ui to my website. Every time I try to load the components they show as regular html instead of how semantic ui is supposed to look.

Here is an example of a class I am exporting:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {Radio} from 'semantic-ui-react';
const RadioExampleToggle = () => <Radio toggle />

class Contact extends Component {  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>DEMO PAGE</h2>
        <p>Just a demo.
        </p>
        {RadioExampleToggle()}
      </div>
    ); 
  }
}
export default Contact;
```

This will show up as a regular radio button which is what I find weird. How do I get it to display the semantic UI versions.

Comment: Is the css loaded in the site? Does anything look like Semantic UI? Can you confirm if the HTML looks like what SemanticUI html should look like?

Comment: Everything looks like plain HTML with no styling. Though the only part that should be styled would be the radio button to my knowledge, since its the only one loaded in

Comment: So the html doesn't have any classes that say stuff like 'ui ...' in it? Based on some cursory reading, it looks like semantic ui HTML has html with classes like `class="ui active button"`

Comment: Correct, regular semantic UI does. I did not use this. Here is an example of a button in react. https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/button/ Just open in sandbox. It is the same type of way I am trying to do radio button

Comment: It is working fine!  I think you haven't imported the cdn tag in `public/index.html` folder here is the working code link https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-spence-2yd1f?fontsize=14

Comment: Not sure what you mean imported the cdn tag. But that working code link is quite useful thank you

Comment: Sorry, you said 'correct', but your link shows that the rendered buttons DO have classes just like normal semantic ui. I inspected the elements and the classes were there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try import CSS file from semantic-ui.

import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'

Comment: Hi, im using semantic ui react. not semantic UI. I installed it with yarn. Its why my code doesnt toss an error and still displayed a radio button. See here https://react.semantic-ui.com/usage

Comment: Yes. but after install, you will need to import css file manually.
http://prntscr.com/pvygox

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Put it in your index.js

```
const styleLink = document.createElement("link");
styleLink.rel = "stylesheet";
styleLink.href = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui/dist/semantic.min.css";
document.head.appendChild(styleLink);
```

Doing it this way will also help you when your app offers theme switching functionality.

[code sample](https://codesandbox.io/embed/semantic-ui-example-6ptkx)